# Important div tag commented out when on production mode

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, page-layouts, setup-di-compile, deployment

We noticed that some of our page layout has been broken. Did some debugging and found out that when in production mode there are some errors with the tags. Specifically:

```
<!--?php  <?php  <?php  <?php  <?php  <?php            <div class="page-wrapper"-->
```

Normally it should be:

```
<div class="page-wrapper">
```

We cleared all caches, switched to developer mode where the tag appears normally. 
Could someone suggest how to debug this for production mode?

We tried to disable all the 3rd party modules, disable all caches, checked most recent cms blocks and pages for div errors. Maybe someone can describe what happens when Magento does the compiling for production mode?

Answer (score 0):

2 possible solutions for Magento 2.2.10 version: 
1) Disable "Minify HTML";
2) Apply patch from this post: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/24992